# Getting a value by name in javascript/razor application

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have an asp application in which i have to use javascript to get the value of an element

```
@for(int i=0; i< Model.Count; i++) {
    <input type="text" value="@Model[i].age" name="age@(i)" />
    HtmlActionLink("new age","Change", new { age = "age" + i.ToString()
});
                                     }
```

I need to get the value of each tag `age` : `new { age = "age" + i.ToString()` didn't work and i have to replace it by a script javascript using `document.getElementsByName` method

How can i modify my code to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add a class to each input element that gives it some meaning (e.g. 'input-age'):

```
<input class="input-age" type="text" value="@Model[i].age" name="age@(i)" />
```

And then you could select all of the inputs by class name and not need to rely on the dynamically assigned name from the view engine:

```
var ages = document.querySelectorAll('input.input-age');
```

Or if you need to find the value for a specific age index, without adding a class name:

```
var ageIndex = 4;
var age = document.querySelector('input[name="age' + ageIndex + '"]').value;
```

FYI, for IE, it will only work in versions 8 or higher because of the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) function, but you could use other methods.

If jQuery was on the table, you could not change anything and use the "starts with" selector to get all "age" elements:

```
var ages = $('input[name^="age"]');
```

Or, after adding a class name:

```
var ages = $('.input-age');
```

Or, hunt down the value for a specific input:

```
var ageIndex = 4;
var age = $('input[name="age' + ageIndex + '"]').val();
```

With the last example, you don't need to add the class name;

Comment: But i need just the current value of age not all the ages' table

Comment: @Lamloumi: How do you define "the current value of age"? There are clearly zero-to-many age inputs available on your page.

Comment: i mean the value of tag having `name="age@(i)"`